# .htaccess rewriting rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Good Evening All,

I am having a little trouble with a .htaccess file that I was hoping some of you would be able to help me with. The first statement that we are rewriting (that rewrites my website so that the index.php is removed) - Statement One - functions perfectly so there are no issues with that, however when I try and remove the ?ID= from listing?ID=name it does not seem to want to work. The statement which for some reason does not function is attached in Statement Two.

**Statement One**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(index\.php)
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

**Statement Two**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^listing/(.*) listing?ID=$1 [PT]
```

Any help that anyone would be able to offer would be greatly appreciated.

Matthew

Comment: Can you give a sample URL on how statement 2 is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to to turn on the rewrite engine again.

Comment: No, you need to turn it on since there is a `[L]` in Statement 1.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. After removing "RewriteEngine on" the page still fails to render. Any other ideas?

Comment: @enchance oops didn't see that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but from your text I gather you want to turn listing?ID=123 into listing/123, right?

In that case you need the rewrite rule the other way round. This should work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ID=(.+)
RewriteRule ^listing(.*) /listing/%1 [QSA]
```